# Titanium httpClient, how to permanently store cookies

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

In my Titanium app, im using rest api which uses cookies for authentication/session handling.

Everything works fine, cookies are automatically used by httpClient until I restart my app.

Is there something specific I need to do, to permanently save cookies?

Im using TiSDK 6.0.1, android.

Comment: Can't you just store the cookie in local storage like this: Ti.App.Properties.setObject(your_cookie, 'cookie');?

Comment: I was in impression that this should be done automatically by the httpClient?

Comment: I've heard about systemCookies but as far as I can read in the docs it's for Android only. I think you have to try to store them by yourself using local storage.